# Didn't get the value init() but in viewDidload() method in swift

Tags: swift, init, viewdidload

I am passing dat from another viewcontroller to tableview?

I am getting value in viewDidload method but not in init() method.

### Putting my code Down

```
@IBOutlet var uiTblCompanyResultView: UITableView!
var companyName=""
var countryCode=""
var townCode=""

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    // ERROR: Property 'self.animator' not initialized at super.init call
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    println("init company \(companyName)")
    println(countryCode)
    println(townCode)
}

//init(companyName : String, countryCode : String) {
  //  self.companyName = companyName
 //   self.countryCode = countryCode
//}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    println("viewDidLoad company \(companyName)")
    println(countryCode)
    println(townCode)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

### The controller where i am passing the data on click

```
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        let viewcomapnyResultController =  self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("companyResultController") as   viewCompanyResultController

        viewcomapnyResultController.companyName=self.txtFieldCompName.text
        viewcomapnyResultController.countryCode=self.countryCode
        viewcomapnyResultController.townCode=self.townCode

        self.showViewController(viewcomapnyResultController as UIViewController, sender:  viewcomapnyResultController)
      }
```

Can u please let me know ...how i can get the data init() method?

Comment: `init` is called when you call `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`. So of course there is no data you can't access, because you haven't assigned it. Unfortunately if you instantiate from a storyboard there is no good way to change this. Can't you move the code that uses this data to `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: @MatthiasBauch.. Ok sure..i will do that...is there any way that i can call init method before viewDidLoad() with passed data?